# Gradle test Unit tests - Run all except one or few - Command line

Tags: unit-testing, command-line, gradle

I have bunch of JUnit unit tests in my projects. Build system is Gradle. OS: Windows/Linux.

Test (Unit tests) come free in Gradle i.e. if you run "**gradle clean build**" Gradle will also run "test" task (to run your Unit tests). I know how can I run all tests in a test folder, of a specific test at command line. Ex: See 23.13.3 and 23.13.4 sections in Gradle user guide: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test

**My question:**

I want to run all tests except one or some. How can I do this in Gradle at command line (rather than using exclude(s) within test { ... } section in build.gradle or higher level .gradle file).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could conditionally add an exclusion based on a property value.

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty('excludeTests')) {
        exclude project.property('excludeTests')
    }
}
```

You could then do something like this from the command line.

```
$ gradle -PexcludeTests=org.foo.MyTest build
```

Comment: I think that might work (as last option). I thought Gradle test tasks already had these command line options inbuilt (like for running a single test using -Dsingle.test=...)  thanks.

Comment: The `test.single` property is the only one available. There is no equivalent property for exclusions.

Comment: From what I understand project properties are added with "-P", "-D" is for system ones at least on the 1.12 i'm using.
$ gradle -PexcludeTests=org.foo.MyTest build

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude more than one test per command line, here an enhanced version of Mark's answer (testet in gradle 6.8.2):

```
    if (project.hasProperty('excludeTests')) {
        project.properties['excludeTests']?.replaceAll('\\s', '')?.split('[,;]').each {
           exclude "${it}"
        }
    }
```

On the command line you can now specify more than one test for exclusion:

```
$ gradlew test -PexcludeTests="**/bar*, **/foo.SomeTest*"
```

The separator may be ";" or ",", with or without following space.