# Excluding a single test method in Gradlew

Tags: java, gradle, junit, gradlew

I am trying to exclude a single test method from a test file in my gradle project. I have excluded the entire test file as below which works fine.

./gradlew -PexcludeTests="com/in/Mytest*"

The above works and excludes all the test methods in the test file. However, I am looking for a command-line way where I can exclude just one test method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle test Unit tests - Run all except one or few - Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809485/gradle-test-unit-tests-run-all-except-one-or-few-command-line)

Comment: @amseager That excludes the whole class, the OP is asking if it is possible to exclude a single test (method).

Comment: That is right. The above link does not answer my question. The above link talks about excluding an entire test class. I am looking to exclude one test method in the class from the command line so that I can use the same command from the build python script.